# Drupal 7 Forms API Conditional Logic not working in IE

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-forms

I have a drupal 7 form with a bunch of fields:

```
$form['account_type'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Utility Account Type'),
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => necp_enrollment_administration_portal_account_type_options(),
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#default_value' => isset($form_state['values']['account_type']) ? $form_state['values']['account_type'] : '',
);

// Should show if account_type = 1
$form['home_wrapper'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#states' => array(
    'visible' => array(
      ':input[name="account_type"]' => array('value' => 1),
    ),
  ),
);
$form['home_wrapper']['first_name_1'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Primary Account First Name'),
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#default_value' => isset($form_state['values']['first_name_1']) ? $form_state['values']['first_name_1'] : '',
  '#states' => array(
    'required' => array(
      ':input[name="account_type"]' => array('value' => 1),
    ),
  ),
);
$form['home_wrapper']['last_name_1'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Primary Account Last Name'),
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#default_value' => isset($form_state['values']['last_name_1']) ? $form_state['values']['last_name_1'] : '',
  '#states' => array(
    'required' => array(
      ':input[name="account_type"]' => array('value' => 1),
    ),
  ),
);

// Should show if account_type = 2
$form['business_wrapper'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#states' => array(
    'visible' => array(
      ':input[name="account_type"]' => array('value' => 2),
    ),
  ),
);
$form['business_wrapper']['company_name'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Company/Organization'),
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#default_value' => isset($form_state['values']['company_name']) ? $form_state['values']['company_name'] : '',
  '#states' => array(
    'required' => array(
      ':input[name="account_type"]' => array('value' => 2),
    ),
  ),
);
```

In Firefox/Chrome/Opera all versions this form behaves as it should. However in all versions of IE the form initializes with display:none; style on all of the conditional fields regardless of what the value in account_type is. Changing the selected option of account_type does not effect the hidden status.

Any tips on debugging this form would be awesome.

Notes:

- I am not much of a Drupal developer, I inherited this site. Just trying to iron out the last couple bugs so we can go live
- there are more fields than are listed above, I just gave you some of the applicable ones so that you could get the gist of how my forms were setup
- current url for the form in development: https://northeastcleanpower.com/enroll_new
- I'm using http://www.browserstack.com/ to debug IE 7 - 10pp4 (I think we only have to support 8 and up though)

I've also tried:

- `':select[name="account_type"]' => array('value' => 1),`
- `'#edit-account-type' => array('value' => 1),`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. Hopefully this will help someone in a similar situation to mine.

```
':input[name="account_type"]' => array('value' => 1),
```

needed to be:

```
':input[name="account_type"]' => array('value' => "1"),
```

Apparently, the javascript in IE was evaluating literal type/value not just value: `1 !== "1"` etc. Once I fixed this it started working like a champ.

also there was another instance in my code where the value was coming from a PHP variable, It wouldn't accept the variable as an int, but accepted it as a string...

```
':input[name="account_type"]' => array('value' => "$id"),
```

Comment: You da man! I had `$form['field_movie_credit'][$lang][$key]['field_movie_credit_character']['#states']['visible'] = array(
          ':input[name="field_movie_credit[' . $lang . '][' . $key . '][field_movie_credit_role][' . $lang . ']"]' => array('value' => $character_role_id),` and changed it to `$form['field_movie_credit'][$lang][$key]['field_movie_credit_character']['#states']['visible'] = array(
          ':input[name="field_movie_credit[' . $lang . '][' . $key . '][field_movie_credit_role][' . $lang . ']"]' => array('value' => "$character_role_id"),` and BOOM! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the jQuery input selector is failing for whatever reason. Can you try replacing `:input[name="account_type"]` with `#edit-account-type`

Comment: this did not seem to work, I also tried `#edit-account-type option:selected`

Comment: in that case, perhaps the selector isn't even running. When I get a moment I'll look for the specific behavior that does the states so i can see where to put a line break.

Comment: thanks for your help man, I appreciate you taking a sec to help.